# JSON Unexpected End Of Input on Ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get some data from server via asmx web service. 
If I  call the service directly from browser, i can able to get json data and it is valid (Checked from jsonlint) but if i call from my app with ajax post method then it's giving parse error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at n.parseJSON (http://172.17.0.xxx/ptm//plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4:5497)
at ub (http://172.17.0.xxx/ptm//plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4:7521)
at x (http://172.17.0.xxx/ptm//plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4:10935)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://172.17.0.xxx/ptm//plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4:14765)
```

I've a lot of functions to get data and all of them working expect this one and this function working well till yesterday.
Also, if I run web service on localhost I can get data from web service with ajax call from localhost.
I've checked a lot of article and question about this error and tried to change header but it didn't solve my problem.

My Header
[image]

Method to get data

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://172.17.0.xxx/SmartMobileWS/SmartMobileWS.asmx/GetEfficiencyFromConsolidate",
    data: { startDate: GetFormattedDate(new Date(dt1)), endDate: GetFormattedDate(new Date(dt2)) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
```

Web Service

```
          [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void GetEfficiencyFromConsolidate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)

  string jsoNresult = DataTableToJsonObj(CheckDatatableForJson(dtResult));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsoNresult);
        }
```

Response
[image]

### **Edit:**

My problem solved after publishing web service to another server. I really don't know what is the cause of this problem. Is there any settings on IIS site or application pool ?

Comment: Was your browser test a POST or a GET? If the latter, are you sure the proper JSON is being returned on POST requests?

Comment: Sounds like the there is some character that is causing it to fail... Look at the network request in the console and look at what is being returned.

Comment: It is a HTTP Post request.

Comment: @epascarello there is no data on response. This request has no response data available.

Comment: There is no data or response? You do not see a response in the Network panel?

Comment: Which response are you asking ? Of course there is alot of response from other methods, I'am clicking my function name from results and request header already shared, in Response tab for related method there is no data available. @epascarello I am adding a scren shot to first message.

Comment: Can you check the ASMX which sends the JSON?  There may be a limit to the amount of data, sometimes this is set at 65536 such as web.config `maxrequestlength`.

Comment: Did you deploy your services explicitly for `172.17.0.111`?

Comment: Did you add any logs/breakpoints on the server to see what is happening there? How is the Ajax call being called on the client?

Comment: BTW, can you send this request by Google Chrome Postman?

Comment: @Valijon, yes I did and I can get data from browser? Now I will try with postman.

Comment: Maybe your IIS checks `user agent` header by some rules?

Comment: @epascarello I didn't try because I can't install remote debugging component to server.